# mysqli_num_rows always display 1 in PHP (workbench display OK)

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following code to display the number if records in the table, it always display 1 even if I change the column name to another column name;

However the same query in workbench displays the correct number of records. See screenshot;

[image: workbench]

```
$con = @mysqli_connect( "localhost:3306", "root", "P@ssw0rd", "classicmodels" ) or die ("Couldn't connect to server");
    //get total number of records
    $query = "SELECT count(checkNumber) FROM payments";
    $result = mysqli_query ( $con, $query) or die ("Couldn't execute SELECT query: ". mysqli_error($con));
    $rec_count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    echo $rec_count."<br>";
```

Comment: Of course it is going to be one row, since you are only selecting COUNT() and not grouping by anything. What did you expect? COUNT() itself will store the number of records but in one row.

Comment: @apriede. Oh sir, how stupid I am. Now I understand my mistake. Thanks for showing my fault.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is because `num_rows` displays the number of rows you fetched, in this case, that's only one. You should get the `count(checkNumber)` field from the database, that contains the number of rows, not the `num_rows` function.

It's nicer to count it as a variable, like `COUNT(someField) as FieldCount`

Answer (score 1):

There will only ever be one row in the results. You should fetch the record and then echo $record['count(checkNumber)']. (Aliasing will make indexing more intuitive).

Answer (score 1):

You are using count function in query and it will give answer in one row. to use get correct answer you can remove count() and leave the rest of the code same as it is. See the following code.

```
  $con = @mysqli_connect( "localhost:3306", "root", "P@ssw0rd", "classicmodels" ) or die ("Couldn't connect to server");
//get total number of records
//I have Removed COUNT() from query
$query = "SELECT checkNumber FROM payments";
$result = mysqli_query ( $con, $query) or die ("Couldn't execute SELECT query: ". mysqli_error($con));
$rec_count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

echo $rec_count."<br>";
```

OR

You can use count() function and get the correct answer like this.

```
$con = @mysqli_connect( "localhost:3306", "root", "P@ssw0rd", "classicmodels" ) or die ("Couldn't connect to server");
//get total number of records
$query = "SELECT count(checkNumber) FROM payments";
$result = mysqli_query ( $con, $query) or die ("Couldn't execute SELECT query: ". mysqli_error($con));
while($rec_row = mysqli_fetch_row($result))
{
    $rec_count=$rec_row['count(checkNumber)'];
}

echo $rec_count."<br>";
```